# Classes, transitive sets and unions/intersections.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to solve:

Let $X$ be a class of transitive sets. then $\cup X$ is transitive. If $X \ne \emptyset$ then $\cap X$ is transitive.

My definition of transitive is: $\forall y \in x (y \subseteq x)$

I'm not sure how to proceed, other than taking an x in the union and trying to show it is a subset.

Comment: Do not delete the question so that others with the same problem will be able to find an answer.

Comment: "other than taking an x..."  is the right way to proceed.It is always good to proceed directly from the def'ns.It may turn out to be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a \in \bigcup X$. This means that $a \in x$ for some $x \in X$. Since $x$ is transitive, $a \subseteq x$. Since $x \subseteq \bigcup X$, we have $a \subseteq \bigcup X$. So, $\bigcup X$ is transitive.

Let $a \in \bigcap X$. This means that $a \in x$ for all $x \in X$. Since every such $x$ is transitive, $a \subseteq x$. So, $\forall x \in X\ : a \subseteq x$. This implies $a \subseteq \bigcap X$. So, $\bigcap X$ is transitive.